# Jupyter notebooks - How do I change the cell colour of different slide types?

Tags: jupyter

I'm creating a presentation in jupyter notebooks where I have slides of different types. I would like to make the background colour of the different slide types different so that I can more easily search through the slides. For example, I would like to make the "skip" slide types have a gray background. I found the snippet included that will let me change all cells throughout the document, but I'm not sure where to go from here as I'm not familiar with javascript.

[image: jupyter notebook snippet]

Comment: see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50824920/11305111)

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. I would like to put some css or javascript in one cell at the top and have it go through all the cells in the notebook and colour the backgrounds based on what slide type they are.