# How can I get rid of or recolour the background of ipywidgets frames in a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter Notebook running in VS Code with an `ipywidgets` button. The button gets displayed in a layout frame with a white background. I'd like to get rid of that frame, or make its background transparent. I've tried putting it inside a `Layout` object such as an `HBox`, but the layout component renders inside this white container.

I suspect this can only be controlled in the VS Code Jupyter extension, but thought I'd ask anyway.

Here is a minimal example of the code I'm using to create the button in the notebook:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

button = widgets.Button(description='Click me')
button.on_click(lambda x: print('Clicked!'))
button
```

[image: Jupyter Notebook ipywidget frame]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant source code for this in the [microsoft/vscode-jupyter](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter) GitHub repo is [src/webviews/webview-side/ipywidgets/renderer/styles.css](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/blob/main/src/webviews/webview-side/ipywidgets/renderer/styles.css), which at the time of this writing, just contains:

```css
.cell-output-ipywidget-background {
    background: white !important;
}
```

The relevant GitHub feature-request issue ticket is [Add support for theming of IPyWidgets #7161](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7161). Quoting from the discussion thread:

[DonJayamanne](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7161#issuecomment-901379444):

> We hardcode the background, as IPYWidgets doesn't understand VS Code themes. & it defaults to white backgrounds in jupyter & jupyter lab,
> If we want to fix this, we need to get our support of ipywidgets to understand vscode themes (fonts, etc).

[martinRenou](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7161#issuecomment-1243513547):

> I believe this can be achieved by making a bridge from the vscode theme (CSS variables?) to the jupyterlab theme.
>
> ipywidgets (and other libraries for Jupyter) use the JupyterLab CSS variables for respecting the theme.
>
> It might just be a matter of defining the needed CSS variables using the current VSCode theme.

[chandradharkoneti](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7161#issuecomment-1257407086):

> For anyone interested:
> I have found a hacky sacky solution.
>
> Make sure VS Code is closed(at least no jupyter related things should be running on it[ I personally closed it completely and reopened it for editing the below file]).
>
> Open file explorer, go to:
>
> `C:\Users\<your_username_here>\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\out\webviews\webview-side\ipywidgetsRenderer`
>
> Open the **ipywidgetsRenderer.js** file (using notepad++ or notepad or even VSCode(before letting any jupyter stuff run)) and
>
> wherever you see `cell-output-ipywidget-background` followed by `background: white`, replace white with black.

You can find the list of other VS Code CSS variables you could use instead of hardcoding a colour if you open the devtools with `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` and then click on the `.monaco-workbench` element and search for "background".

A different (maybe better?) workaround was found in a different but related thread: [White background for ipywidgets in dark themes
#9403](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9403):

[Filip-K](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9403#issuecomment-1072547892):

> ```
> %%html
> <style>
> .cell-output-ipywidget-background {
>    background-color: transparent !important;
> }
> .jp-OutputArea-output {
>    background-color: transparent;
> }  
> </style>
> ```

I *would* suggest to put this in [an IPython startup file](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#startup-files), but the VS Code Jupyter extension [doesn't support those right now](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/2144), and instead only has the `jupyter.runStartupCommands` setting, but that doesn't seem to support such an HTML cell.